# How to export shp and TIFF files from a list with Python

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, indexerror

I'm a beginner in Python, and I am trying to write code that receives a list of TIFFs and shapefiles from an input folder.

The objective is:

> Do a clip to a raster using the Extract By Mask and if the file is a
> shp, do the clip.

After this, I have to export all this files "clipped" to an output folder. But I don't know how export this files with the original names. I'm trying using the `os.path` but something is going wrong.

My code:

```
import os,arcpy

    def clip(clip_features,input_folder,output_folder):
        arcpy.env.workspace = input_folder
        desc_clip = arcpy.Describe(clip_features)
        geometryType = desc_clip.shapeType
        list_fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        print (list_fc,geometryType)
        list_rt = arcpy.ListRasters()
        print list_rt
        files = []
        out_folder = os.listdir(output_folder)
        geometry = None
        outExtractByMask = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask
        out_feature_class = os.path.join(output_folder,files[1].split("_")[0])
        if in_features.endswith('tif'):
            return outExtractByMask(list_rt, clip_features)
            outExtractByMask(out_feature_class)
        elif in_features.endswith('shp'):
                return arcpy.Clip_analysis(list_fc, clip_features, out_feature_class)
    
    
    #The error thats show for me is: "out_feature_class = os.path.join(output_folder,files[1].split("_")[0])
    #IndexError: list index out of range"
```

Comment: Is your code really indented as you show it? If not (and is simply a paste error) correct it and show it as it should be.

Comment: "Something is going wrong" is a difficult problem statement to which to respond. Please [Edit] your Question to format the code so it won't fail to execute and provide more details on the nature of the error or problem you are encountering. It might help if you start thinking about the task differently -- Instead of a bunch of files, you have a set of TIFFs which may have a mated shapefile that needs to be used to clip; once framed this way the program logic suggests itself.

Comment: Hi @Hornbydd I edited my code, now is indented correctly with de error. I don't know how to fix this...

Comment: Hi @Vince, so the clip_feature needs to be in another folder to not show in list_fc? I'm new here, it's first time I ask something here

Comment: `files` is an empty list. You never populate it with anything.